# closing the bootstrap modal window using angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal model like this

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/

I would like to know how I can call in the function closing the modal window
Because at the moment I have that, When I delete item (which display modal window, he will disappeard but dark background blocking the page does not disappear.

```
App.directive("menuDeleteCard", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: '/directives/menu-delete-card/menu-delete-card-template.ejs',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.deleteCard = (indexList, indexCard) => {
                $scope.board.lists[indexList].cards.splice(indexCard, 1)

            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: where is the fiddle for your code?

Comment: the difference between mine and this jsfiddle is just content, my project is too big to give a demo here :( I have in modal window option delete card, when I delete card modal window (this which displayed white window with content disappear, but background not disappear

Comment: it gets closed fine for me

Comment: I mean that I have problem that when u click on Card is displayed modal window, wiht option delete this card, so when I delete this card white window is disappear but not background which is blocking page, and here is problem how to fix it??

Comment: Stop using bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: Which differences is ?